# In page Payment script security needs

Tags: javascript, payment-gateway, payment

Currently, I'm working in a Fintech StartUp. We have already implemented our payment solution with redirect in a checkout page hosted in our domain (like https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout).

Now, we are going to implement a solution that allow payments directly in the merchants page, but in order to maintain PCI complaint also in the merchants page we need to provide a script, that the merchant can insert in their website, where the sensitive data is collected and forwarded to our APIs (like https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment).

I have to write a *JavaScript* script that enables "in page" merchant payments, but I don't find in any places a list of the security needs.

Checking several PSP that provide the same functionality I find some of security needs:

1. The script and the form that collect sensitive data must be hosted in the PSP domain and inserted in the merchant webpage with an iFrame.
2. The ids of inputs on the form that collect Credit card data must be randomly generated.
3. The merchants website must load the script directly from our domain in order to remain PCI complaint (There is any way to check this point?).
4. Javascript file must be minified and uglified.

My questions: are there any document that explains all the recommended security needs of this typology of script? Otherwise, is my security list enough? Are there some errors in my list?

Answer (score 3):

Since you are going to use a script in a page (as opposed to redirecting to a payment page maintained by the service provider), you are subject to [PCI-DSS A-EP requirements](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/PCI-DSS-v3_2_1-SAQ-A_EP.pdf?agreement=true&time=1575055496956).

JavaScript is not explicitly mentioned there, but the general requirements you need to follow are (cryptographic measures for instance).

**EDIT**

Beside Conor's relevant comment below, a few comments on some of the 
security points you mention in your question

> The script and the form that collect sensitive data must be hosted in
>   the PSP domain and inserted in the merchant webpage with an iFrame.

It does not have to be inserted in an IFRAME, it can be injected as a script directly in the page (see for instance [Stripe's API](https://stripe.com/docs/api))

> The merchants website must load the script directly from our domain in
>   order to remain PCI complaint (There is any way to check this point?).

This is their problem, not yours - you just provide the scripts and take responsibility for them.

> Javascript file must be minified and uglified.

This does not add any reliable security (the minification and uglification is done for performance, and maybe some kind of obfuscation which does not hurt but cannot be tagged as "security measure")

Please also note that the JS part of the code is inherently insecure, you must not rely on it for the security of your data (apart some few general points described in OWASP). The security you need mostly to worry about is on the server (backend) side. You should always assume that what you receive from your frontend is insecure.

Comment: +1, but one question: does that document represent guidelines for companies that are trying to use such a payment flow provided by a 3rd party, or does that document reflect standards for 3rd parties trying to implement such a payment flow and provide it to customers? Because I suspect the document you linked to is for the former, but the OP is attempting the latter.

Comment: @ConorMancone: you are correct, I did not correctly interpret the question. This document is indeed for a customer who wants to integrate a payment system into their own pages (instead of redirecting to someone, in which case they would be at most PCI-DSS A, and not everyone agrees even on that as I found out). But then the question is basically about best practices when writing SaaS software, and specifically the JS APIs provided to the customer. A very legitimate question on its own but I do not think there is anything special about financial systems from that perspective (?).

Comment: Doing that effectively makes you a credit card processor, which has far more rules and regulations to follow to remain PCI compliant...

Comment: @ConorMancone: yes of course, and you are subject to relevant PCI-DSS requirements. They do not cover the software (code) part, though (at least I could never find anything), beside the fact that it "must be secure". Which falls back to general app security (OWASP, ASVS, ...).

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to give a frame-challenge as an answer.

To recap: you're trying to implement the most important part of a process for which privacy is critical, you are operating in a tightly regulated market, and are asking strangers on the internet for help with the basics of security.

I don't think that is going to go well.  My serious suggestion is that you should start by retaining a contractor who has substantial familiarity with the relevant regulations and security issues involved, and get them to make this list for you and check for proper implementation.  Otherwise the internet is not going to be able to help with the inevitable security audit when things go south...